# posiçao de vetor em C nao recebe novo valor na atribuição

Tags: c, array

O valor de um índice de um vetor não recebe atribuição;

1. Ler 10 valores reais e armazenar em um vetor. Modifique o vetor de modo que os valores ímpares sejam aumentados em 5%, e os valores pares sejam
   aumentados em 2%. Imprima o vetor resultante.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n[11]={0};

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("digite o %d numero: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       if(n[i]%2==0)
       {
           n[i] = n[i]*0.02;
       }
       else
       {
            n[i] = n[i]*0.05;
       }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", i+1, n[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cara tem um problema, somente números inteiros são pares ou impar e você disse numero real, editei seu codigo aí, no caso eu converto de float para real uma variavel auxiliar e verifico, e para aumentar vc multiplica por 1.05 ou 1.02 no caso, multiplicando por 0.05 vc ta diminuido vc ta pegando 5% do valor, agora por 1.05, você aumenta para 105% do valor, da uma olhada no código e tenta entender, e sempre use uma constante, ou uma varaivel para definir tamanho, que facilita a manipulação do array

```html
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int tam=10;
    float n[tam];

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
        printf("digite o %d numero: \n", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &n[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
       int a = n[i];
       if(a%2==0)
       {
           n[i] = n[i]*1.02;
       }
       else
       {
            n[i] = n[i]*1.05;
       }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++)
    {
        printf("n[%d] = %.2f\n", i+1, n[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```